# Beginner Shell, can't find the issue (array sorting)

Tags: shell, sorting, zsh

Working on a little script which put random numbers in a 10 000 size array and then sort all this array with the method ask during the course.

I've done this code but it seem that it begin to sort (when I test I have some "a" that are printed but not as much as supposed to and I don't understand why)

I'm believing the problem come fromes my test on val array, and it's probably a beginner error but I don't really know how to find the problem on th web as I don't really now which line is the problem.

I don't necessary need an answer, just some clues to find it could be good :)

Here is my code: (new to stackoverflow so I don't know how to put a good code view directly, if anyone can show me)

```
for i in `seq 1 10000`;
do
    val[${i}]=$RANDOM
done
echo `date +"%M.%S.%3N"`

FLAG=0
until [ $FLAG -eq 1 ]
do
    FLAG=1
    for j in `seq 1 9999`;
    do
        if [ ${val[${j}]} -gt ${val[${j+1}]} ]
        then
            TMP=${val[${j}]}
            val[${j}]=${val[${j+1}]}
            val[${j+1}]=$TMP
            FLAG=0
            echo a
        fi
    done
done

echo `date +"%M.%S.%3N"`
```

as asked I can't really have a useful output as I just want the date before and after the sort operation. But the sort is just supposed to put values from lower to higher by taking them two by two and invert them if necessary. Doing this until no numbers are inverted.

Edit: I tried with manual number:
10 3 6 9 1

when running it by putting echo ${val[*]} in the for loop it just print 4 times the same list in the same order, so I'm guessing it doesn't work at all... Is my use of "if" wrong ?

Edit 2: At the begining, I did it in C# and I wanted to do it in shell then, firstly because I wanted to practice shell and then because I wanted to compare efficiency and time needed for the same thing. here is the C# code, working.

```
            Random random = new Random();
            int[] _tab = new int[100000];
            for (int i = 0; i < _tab.Length; i++)
            {
                _tab[i] = random.Next(1, _tab.Length);
            }

            bool perm;
            int tmp;
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            do
            {
                perm = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < (_tab.Length - 1); i++)
                {
                    if (_tab[i] > _tab[i + 1])
                    {
                        tmp = _tab[i];
                        _tab[i] = _tab[i + 1];
                        _tab[i + 1] = tmp;
                        perm = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            while (perm == true);

            Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - dt).TotalMilliseconds);
            Console.Read();
```

Thanks :)

Comment: use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box on highlighted text to format as code/data/output.  (We don't ask people to goto external sites here in the Stackexchange, your Q is expected to have all the info required, including small input, expected ouput, current code/ouput/error msgs and your thoughts about the problem and how you got there ;-) ) . Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Was trying to click on it and then pasting, so it didn't work! ^-^ Good to know! :)

Comment: note also my comment about small sample input, expected output ... ;-) Maybe run `seq 1 10`, force your array with those values, then you can predict expected output. Good luck.

Comment: I did it, but it's quite hard because I didn't want any output else than the 2 date at the beginning and at the end. But I added what kind of sort I wanted and how it is supposed to work. Yeah Indeed I could have try to do it with non-random numbers.

Comment: once its working with a small set of test data, *then* you can "turn it up" to 10000 to see if it is really working ;-). AND I'm not clear at all by what you mean by " I didn't want any output else than the 2 date at the beginning and at the end." This is why small sample input and expected output are important in the . Do you really just mean output =`20.23.456`   and `22.47.789`? Good luck.

Comment: Yeah I don't care about printing the sorted array. Just want to show the 2 times to be able to quickly have a look at the time it take.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing it this way? Once you get to a large enough set of numbers, it's going to be a lot more efficient to dump out to a stream that GNU sort or similar can process in bulk.

Comment: It just that it must fit the method see during the course, Of course I wouldn't have do it this way If I have the choice. But as the teacher want us to use this way. I must do it this way. I have already do it in C# but I was wondering if shell was faster to do this. And trying to translate it from C# to shell. (I will add the C# code on the original post)

Comment: (BTW, consider `for ((i=1; i<=10000; i++)); do` instead of `for i in $(seq 1 10000)` -- the former uses only functionality built into the shell and operates in constant memory; the latter runs a subprocess [which *isn't* a POSIX-standardized tool and isn't guaranteed to be available everywhere], reads all its output into memory, and splits that output into a bunch of individual strings).

Comment: anyhow. If you want to track what's going on during a script's operation, `set -x` is your friend -- or `zsh -x yourscript`.

Comment: and/or `time mySortScript`. Good luck.

Comment: BTW, as a piece of unsolicited advice -- as someone who's learning, be careful with zsh; it's easy to get into habits (like underquoting) that'll serve you poorly if you try to write code that'll work reliably on other shells later. [Part of the intent behind zsh is to be less error-prone to work with than more strictly POSIX-compliant shells, and it successfully fulfils that intent, but that means you don't develop the habits necessary to write robust code in shells that *do* properly follow the POSIX sh standard].

Comment: thanks for your advice and for the -x option that I didn't know, very useful to debug !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my understanding that you want to know why this script is not producing an "a" indicating the ordering of the array of the numbers initially produced in the "for" loop is correct, then here is a solution:

**The syntax is incorrect for your variable expansion**.  The `${var}` cannot have math operators inside the braces, because they have different meaning here. In a normal non-associative array Zsh handles subscripts with some basic math support, so you can use `${array[var+1]}` instead of `${array[${var+1}]}` as you previously did.

I suspect the reason this came about - complicated, error prone POSIX syntax - would have been avoided by using simplified Zsh syntax, but as stated in an earlier comment, it would not be portable to other shells.

Some shells support similar features: Bash supports most, but not bare subscripts (`$array[var]`).  Strings may be ordered in Zsh in a similar manner, but the math-context brackets `((` and `))` would have to be replaced with normal test brackets `[[` and `]]` and the array `$val` might have to be defined with special `typeset` options to make the strings compare in the desired manner; that is, they might have to be padded and right or left aligned. For comparing enumeration types, like Jan - Feb, it gets a little more complicated with associative arrays and case-conversion.

Here is the script with the appropriate changes, then again in simplified Zsh:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `seq 1 10000`;
do
    val[$((i))]=$RANDOM
done
echo `date +"%M.%S.%3N"`

FLAG=0
until [ $FLAG -eq 1 ]
do
    FLAG=1
    for j in `seq 1 9999`;
    do
        if [ ${val[$((j))]} -gt ${val[$((j+1))]} ]
        then
            TMP=${val[$((j))]}
            val[$((j))]=${val[$((j+1))]}
            val[$((j+1))]=$TMP
            FLAG=0
            echo a
        fi
    done
done

echo `date +"%M.%S.%3N"`
```

Zsh:

```
#!/bin/zsh
foreach i ( {1..10000} )
    val[i]=$RANDOM
end
echo `date +"%M.%S.%3N"`

FLAG=0
until ((FLAG))
do
    FLAG=1
    foreach j ( {1..9999} )
        if (( val[j] > val[j+1] ))
        then
            TMP=$val[j]
            val[j]=$val[j+1]
            val[j+1]=$TMP
            FLAG=0
            echo a
        fi
    end
done

echo `date +"%M.%S.%3N"`
```